# How to release memory space which occupied by segment-anything？

Tags: python, facebook, pytorch, image-segmentation

I run this code in jupyterlab, using facebook's segment-anything：

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from segment_anything import SamAutomaticMaskGenerator, sam_model_registry
import numpy as np
import gc

def show_anns(anns):
    if len(anns) == 0:
        return
    sorted_anns = sorted(anns, key=(lambda x: x['area']), reverse=True)
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.set_autoscale_on(False)
    polygons = []
    color = []
    for ann in sorted_anns:
        m = ann['segmentation']
        img = np.ones((m.shape[0], m.shape[1], 3))
        color_mask = np.random.random((1, 3)).tolist()[0]
        for i in range(3):
            img[:,:,i] = color_mask[i]
        ax.imshow(np.dstack((img, m*0.35)))


sam = sam_model_registry["default"](checkpoint="VIT_H SAM Model/sam_vit_h_4b8939.pth")
mask_generator = SamAutomaticMaskGenerator(sam)
image = cv2.imread('Untitled Folder/292282 sample.jpg')
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
sam.to(device='cuda')
masks = mask_generator.generate(image)
print(len(masks))
print(masks[0].keys())
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
plt.imshow(image)
show_anns(masks)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show() 
del(masks)
gc.collect()
```

Before I run it, memory cost is about 200MB, and when it completes, memory cost is about 3.4GB, even if I close the notebook or re-run this program, those memory won't be released.
So how to solve the problem?

Comment: how did you determine the memory consumption? how did you "close the notebook"?

Comment: Memory Consumption：RAM usage before and after process running，close the notebook：close the tab of notebook，don’t restart or close jupyter kernel.

Comment: yeah that could be it. your actions had no effect. try different actions.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the code is slightly flawed in the way that it doesn't clear any of the cache on the GPU, a simple fix for this would be to use pytorches `torch.cuda.empty_cache()` command to clear up your Vram before it runs it for a new image, I found that it literally stacks the generated embed's in memory, I even ended up running out of memory on my 16Gb vram AWS DL machine. Hope this helps!

Here's a snippet example for how I used it in their automatic_mask_generator_example notebook:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
from segment_anything import sam_model_registry, SamAutomaticMaskGenerator, SamPredictor
# Free up GPU memory before loading the model
import gc
gc.collect()
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
# -------------------------------------------
sam_checkpoint = "../models/sam_vit_l_0b3195.pth"
model_type = "vit_l"

device = "cuda"

sam = sam_model_registry[model_type](checkpoint=sam_checkpoint)
sam.to(device=device)

mask_generator = SamAutomaticMaskGenerator(sam)
```

Comment: It has no effect.